# Type casting large integers on a 32 bit server

Tags: php

I have the following code.

```
<?php
$id=3001957093; //between 1 and 4,294,967,295
echo($id."\n".(int)$id."\n");
```

On my x86_64 Centos PHP Version 5.5.24 development physical box, `(int)$id` is the same as `$id`.  On my i386 Centos PHP Version 5.5.18 production virtual server, however, `(int)$id` is `-1293010203`.

Reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php, I see:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value
>   of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed).
>   64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except on
>   Windows prior to PHP 7, where it was always 32 bit. PHP does not
>   support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the
>   constant PHP_INT_SIZE, maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX
>   since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5, and minimum value using the constant
>   PHP_INT_MIN since PHP 7.0.0.

Ah ha, that explains it!

On a 32 bit server, how can I ensure that a number between 1 and 4,294,967,295 is an integer?

How can I tell what was the original number (i.e. 3001957093) given the converted value (i.e. -1293010203)?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Comment: If it doesn't fit into an integer, you can't use an integer. Period.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath `is_int` won't work, because the figure will have been converted to a float.

Comment: Can the original value be determined given the converted float?

Comment: @user1032531 Not reliably.  On 64 bit `9.2233720368548E+18 === (9.2233720368548E+18 + 1)` is `true`.

Comment: @user1032531 Where does your original value come from? Is it a constant?  I'm curious why it flipped to negative when all my tests convert to float.

Comment: @Flosculus  The value is a PK of a table storing a document name.  Given the number, I created directories to store the file.  Now, I have a bunch of orphaned files :(   Don't know why it flips negative.  Anything I should check on `phpinfo()` which might explain?

Comment: @Flosculus.  Yes.  `INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94434/discussion-between-flosculus-and-user1032531).